# How can I recover my coins?

Tags: wallet, altcoin

I'm using an alt coin.

The wallet would not sync so I deleted the `blkindex.dat` file to restart the download. I restarted the wallet client and it downloaded all the blocks, but all my coins are gone. Using a block explorer and it says the address does not exist on the network. On the transactions, all the transaction statuses show as unconfirmed.

Is it possible to get my coins back? What caused this to happen?

Comment: Do you still have the wallet.dat file?

Comment: Could you please provide us with the address(es) that show up as nonexistent and the transaction(s) that show up as unconfirmed?

Comment: Which altcoin? Which block explorer?

Comment: Yes I still have the `wallet.dat` file. Address: `PJzuTzakaJfhx18png9NfrSptf395kE45h` and tx id: `68d584bacd375b329b0f79ce153fd32dbd4d00b686e62d6d1c04413f58a753bb`. The alt coin is PMP.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that transaction ID ever succeeded.

Comment: That's why I'm confused. The coins were in my wallet for a good 2-3 months. Then, one day, the wallet wouldn't sync so I deleted the `blkindex.dat` file and once the blocks were downloaded again, all the coins were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Coins can "appear to be there" in unconfirmed status.

It's likely that this transaction never confirmed, and whilst you may have thought that you had the coins, in reality you did not.

Unless there has been a hardfork of the PMP blockchain of some kind, all the evidence would suggest that you never had these coins in the first place. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have your `wallet.dat` file backed up, you have not lost any coins.  You can safely delete your local copy of the blockchain and it will be downloaded again.  Give it time to download everything.

Perhaps you didn't restore the correct backup copy of you `wallet.dat` file.  Or perhaps your `blkindex.dat` file IS your wallet file, just renamed.  Do you have a backup of that?

Try closing your wallet client, replacing your wallet file with a backup, then re-opening your wallet client.

Answer (score 0):

If you did delete your wallet file, check your recycle bin. You should be able to sort via date, and figure it out based on the time you deleted it.

Comment: Did you bother reading the comments? http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32534/how-can-i-recover-my-coins#comment37997_32534